# 2003 Toyota Camry Seat won't move back into upright position

Tags: toyota, camry, seat

My 2003 Toyota Camry seat is having issues where if you tilt for the seat to lean back it goes but when you tilt for the seat to return to an upright position it won't go.

All I hear is the motor when I try to get the seat back up.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Because the seat motor runs when you use the switch, electricity is getting to the motor and the motor is operating. The seat doesn't move forward because a) something's wrong with the gears or levers between the motor and the seat back; and/or the pivot on which the seat back moves is jammed or stuck. The seat back (or the entire seat) will have to be removed from the car so it can be disassembled and fixed.